# What can't I buy?

Tags: mathematics

A certain chain store sells chocolate bars in packets of 17 and 9 only. Clearly, you could not get 8 or 25 bars. Find all quantities of bars that you cannot buy.

Comment: this is clearly an ad for chocolate. I'll be back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can make $17 \times 8 = 136$ and any number above this by replacing a $17$ with $2 \times 9$, to increment the number by $1$. By the time we run out of $17$s to replace ($9 \times 16$), we continue with $17 \times 8 + 9 = 145$ and repeat the trick, until we arrive at $9 \times 17$, at which point we swap that with $17 \times 9$ and start replacing $17$s again.

Looking at the numbers below $136$, we can make any number $n \times 17$ and

1. the following $n$ integers by replacement of $17$ with $2 \times 9$,
2. anything $m\times9$ above this e.g.
   $17$ gives us $18$ by replacement and $26$, $35$, $44$, $53$, $62$, $71$, $80$, $89$, $98$, $107$, $116$, $125$, $134$ by addition of $9$s

Adding all of these we find that the highest number we cannot make is

> $127$

and there are

> $63$

possible numbers below this.

The ones we cannot form are:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 64, 65, 66, 67, 73, 74, 75, 76, 82, 83, 84, 91, 92, 93, 100, 101, 109, 110, 118, 127

Comment: so what quantities can you not buy :p

Comment: I know the question is not answered - I had a PEBKAC error and posted before I had finished writing. Finishing it now.

Comment: +1 anyway of course. It's essentially solved. nice job :)

Comment: I can't find a simple argument why these numbers below 128  cannot be gotten and all others can. Or do I miss this?

Comment: @miracle You can get 1) Any multiple of 9, 2) Any multiple of 17 (call it $n*17$) and 3) the next $n$ numbers after (2). Once (2) and (3) start to overlap, you can form all higher numbers.

Comment: But I also can get 26=17+9 which is neither in 1),2) nor 3)

Comment: @miracle173 whoops. You can get 1) Any multiple of 17 (call it n∗17) 2) the next n numbers after (2) and 3) every 9th number after (1) and (2). Once (2) and (3) for a given n start to overlap, you can form all higher numbers.

Comment: The numbers we can make are of the form $ m \times 9 + n \times 17 \,| \, m, n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge0} $

Answer (score 2):

The numbers we *can* make are of the form $m \times 9 + n \times 17 \,| \, m, n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}$.

As we can see (and as has been said before), the largest number we *can't* make is $127$.

$$
\begin{array}{r|rr}
\text{target} & m & n \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & - & - \\
2 & - & - \\
3 & - & - \\
4 & - & - \\
5 & - & - \\
6 & - & - \\
7 & - & - \\
8 & - & - \\
9 & 1 & 0 \\
10 & - & - \\
11 & - & - \\
12 & - & - \\
13 & - & - \\
14 & - & - \\
15 & - & - \\
16 & - & - \\
17 & 0 & 1 \\
18 & 2 & 0 \\
19 & - & - \\
20 & - & - \\
21 & - & - \\
22 & - & - \\
23 & - & - \\
24 & - & - \\
25 & - & - \\
26 & 1 & 1 \\
27 & 3 & 0 \\
28 & - & - \\
29 & - & - \\
30 & - & - \\
31 & - & - \\
32 & - & - \\
33 & - & - \\
34 & 0 & 2 \\
35 & 2 & 1 \\
36 & 4 & 0 \\
37 & - & - \\
38 & - & - \\
39 & - & - \\
40 & - & - \\
41 & - & - \\
42 & - & - \\
43 & 1 & 2 \\
44 & 3 & 1 \\
45 & 5 & 0 \\
46 & - & - \\
47 & - & - \\
48 & - & - \\
49 & - & - \\
50 & - & - \\
51 & 0 & 3 \\
52 & 2 & 2 \\
53 & 4 & 1 \\
54 & 6 & 0 \\
55 & - & - \\
56 & - & - \\
57 & - & - \\
58 & - & - \\
59 & - & - \\
60 & 1 & 3 \\
61 & 3 & 2 \\
62 & 5 & 1 \\
63 & 7 & 0 \\
64 & - & - \\
65 & - & - \\
66 & - & - \\
67 & - & - \\
68 & 0 & 4 \\
69 & 2 & 3 \\
70 & 4 & 2 \\
71 & 6 & 1 \\
72 & 8 & 0 \\
73 & - & - \\
74 & - & - \\
75 & - & - \\
76 & - & - \\
77 & 1 & 4 \\
78 & 3 & 3 \\
79 & 5 & 2 \\
80 & 7 & 1 \\
81 & 9 & 0 \\
82 & - & - \\
83 & - & - \\
84 & - & - \\
85 & 0 & 5 \\
86 & 2 & 4 \\
87 & 4 & 3 \\
88 & 6 & 2 \\
89 & 8 & 1 \\
90 & 10 & 0 \\
91 & - & - \\
92 & - & - \\
93 & - & - \\
94 & 1 & 5 \\
95 & 3 & 4 \\
96 & 5 & 3 \\
97 & 7 & 2 \\
98 & 9 & 1 \\
99 & 11 & 0 \\
100 & - & - \\
101 & - & - \\
102 & 0 & 6 \\
103 & 2 & 5 \\
104 & 4 & 4 \\
105 & 6 & 3 \\
106 & 8 & 2 \\
107 & 10 & 1 \\
108 & 12 & 0 \\
109 & - & - \\
110 & - & - \\
111 & 1 & 6 \\
112 & 3 & 5 \\
113 & 5 & 4 \\
114 & 7 & 3 \\
115 & 9 & 2 \\
116 & 11 & 1 \\
117 & 13 & 0 \\
118 & - & - \\
119 & 0 & 7 \\
120 & 2 & 6 \\
121 & 4 & 5 \\
122 & 6 & 4 \\
123 & 8 & 3 \\
124 & 10 & 2 \\
125 & 12 & 1 \\
126 & 14 & 0 \\
127 & - & - \\
\hline
128 & 1 & 7 \\
129 & 3 & 6 \\
130 & 5 & 5 \\
131 & 7 & 4 \\
132 & 9 & 3 \\
133 & 11 & 2 \\
134 & 13 & 1 \\
135 & 15 & 0 \\
136 & 0 & 8 \\
137 & 2 & 7 \\
138 & 4 & 6 \\
139 & 6 & 5 \\
140 & 8 & 4 \\
141 & 10 & 3 \\
142 & 12 & 2 \\
143 & 14 & 1 \\
144 & 16 & 0 \\
145 & 1 & 8 \\
146 & 3 & 7 \\
147 & 5 & 6 \\
148 & 7 & 5 \\
149 & 9 & 4 \\
150 & 11 & 3 \\
151 & 13 & 2 \\
152 & 15 & 1 \\
153 & 17 & 0 \\
154 & 2 & 8 \\
155 & 4 & 7 \\
156 & 6 & 6 \\
157 & 8 & 5 \\
158 & 10 & 4 \\
159 & 12 & 3 \\
160 & 14 & 2 \\
161 & 16 & 1 \\
162 & 18 & 0 \\
163 & 3 & 8 \\
164 & 5 & 7 \\
165 & 7 & 6 \\
166 & 9 & 5 \\
167 & 11 & 4 \\
168 & 13 & 3 \\
169 & 15 & 2 \\
170 & 17 & 1 \\
171 & 19 & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$